# What is the complexity in the following case?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose we have a while loop that iterates on the basis of a true-false condition (let suppose whether a queue is empty or not) and it has a for loop inside like:

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    // some lines of code
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Will it be `O(n^2)` or `O(n)`.

***EDIT***

```
 while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        currNode = queue.remove();
        indexToSearch = currNode.data;
        for(i = 0; i < parentArr.length; i++) {
            if(parentArr[i] == indexToSearch) {
                newNode = new BinaryNode(i);
                if(!leftDone) {
                    currNode.left = newNode;
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    leftDone = true;
                } else {
                    currNode.right = newNode;
                    queue.add(newNode);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        leftDone = false;
    }
```

Comment: You're not iterating over a Boolean.

Comment: Are you asking because your function is diverging (running into an endless loop)?

Comment: No i am just analysing. I have got the solution of my problem but was looking whether it is O(n) or not.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you building a binary search tree?

Comment: i am poping the nodes of binary tree from queue. Then i am searching the value of that node in an array. if i find the value then i make it its left child and add to queue, if i find it again then i make it its right child and add to queue and break the for loop as there cannot be more than two child.

Comment: What is in the queue initially?

Comment: only the root node. This is the problem of constructing a tree from its parent array representation where the array holds the index of parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your complexity depends on both n and the size of your queue. So that your complexity would be O(n * queue.size())

(assuming that your other implied lines of code can be ignored)

In order to determine a "useful" complexity class, you need to include all of the parameters that can change the number of iteration you have to go through.

(Also, since you never pop your queue, in the worst case you will have a function that diverges, but I guess it is implied that you pop your queue before or after the loop)

***********EDIT**** (after seing the code)

So you have an array of n values. And wish to construct a tree with n nodes

```
For each node you add: (meaning n times)
    You linearly search your array of values (worst case: you always need to search the entire array, also meaning n times)
```

So your complexity is O(n^2 )

(If you wouldn't be able to make the assumptions above you would get an other complexity because of stuff like 'what if the value is not in the queue' or 'what if my queue is much larger than the array' )

Comment: Let say we have 4 elements in queue, then complexity would be O(4n). Since we are using big O then it is equivalent to O(n). Am i right?? @user2887596

Comment: Yes, if your queue is of constant size, then you are in O(n), as you said. But, if you can not assume that your queue has a constant size, or at least an upper limit on how big it can be, you must take the size of the queue into consideration

Comment: in my case it is growing as well it is decreasing....i want to get a better insight of complexity in these type of cases. Would you explain with my edited code.

Comment: Yes, but, in the end, each node your tree has will be in the queue exactly once, causing exactly one iteration. That is why, in the end your queue will cause n iterations to happen